# Canonical $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space for algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If we define $\mathbb{C}$ as the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ then we have a canonical map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ and so for an algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ we get a canonical $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $H^i(X(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Q})$ for each integer $i\geq 0$.

Being canonical means for example that $\mathrm{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(X)$ acts on it (sometimes non-trivially).

However we do not have a canonical map $\mathbb{Q}_p\to \mathbb{C}$. Is there a way to canonically attach $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the right rank to algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: What does "right rank" mean?

Comment: For smooth proper varieties it should be the same as de Rham cohomology (there may be a better way to formulate it)

Comment: Fixing any map $\mathbb Q_p \to \mathbb C$, not necessarily canonical, still means that $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb R}(X)$ acts on the cohomology.